# What are the benefits of using royal arms?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

One of the main objectives of FFXV is for Noctis to gather the royal arms. These weapons have a lot of in-game lore behind them... but they don't seem all that powerful.

Royal arms drain your health each time you strike an enemy, sometimes have other adverse effects (Axe of the Conqueror greatly reduces defense just by having it equipped), and seem to not gain the damage type bonuses you would expect for a weapon of that class.

Why would I want to have one active?

Comment: sounds similar to the Sword of Kings and Treaty Blade from Final Fantasy XII (original version), both obtained and used in the plot and can also be equipped without a license however both are weak and don't have the greatsword knockback bonus. and the Deifacted Nethicite which can be equipped as an accessory, great in defending against magic but has a consistent Silence which prevents the holder from casting magic.

Comment: I'm not as familiar with FFXII, but that certainly sounds like the same kind of thing. I'm about 20 hours in (got my copy last Friday - I'm actually a filthy casual) and so far these weapons don't even seem that great when you first get them. They're pretty, at least, and that's half the battle.

Comment: or they need some set equip to make them stronger

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Aside from boosting your stats exponentially, there are two benefits for using the Royal Arms:

1. Deals non-specific weapon type damage, which are useful against enemies who have physical resistances. i.e. The Katana of the Warrior functions with mobility and style of a sword, but deals regular damage to enemies who have resistance or weakness to swords.
2. Enhances *Warp Strike*, *Blitz Combos*, and/or *Directional Attacks*  to make them more powerful and effective by giving them additional abilities. [iDigitalTimes Royal Arms](http://www.idigitaltimes.com/final-fantasy-15-royal-arms-guide-tips-and-tricks-master-combat-571485) contains a breakdown of each of the Royal Arm's hidden abilities

> **Sword of the Wise**
>
> 1. Use as you would use a regular sword
> 2. Attack: 194
> 3. Has two-hit warp strike with delayed second hit
> 4. Initial hit of a Blitz combo is the strongest
> 5. Enables backflip as a backward directional attack
>
> **Blade of the Mystic**
>
> 1. Use like a greatsword that can use combos
> 2. Attack: 396
> 3. Initial Blitz hit is slow, but speeds up with subsequent attacks
> 4. Warp-strike begins with three projectiles toward the enemy as Noctis
>    stands in place, then Noctis warps forward with a physical attack
> 5. Pause during a Blitz combo to trigger the Tenacious self-buff that
>    increases Noctis’ Strength by 100 for 10 seconds (does not stack but
>    is repeatable)
>
> **Trident of the Oracle**
>
> 1. Use like a polearm
> 2. Attack: 388
> 3. Creates afterimage of Noctis after each attack and performs up to
>    three additional attacks there
> 4. Performs aerial diving warp-strike of up to three hits with follow-up
>    afterimage attacks
> 5. Allows you to use an evasive leap and subsequent aerial dive attack as
>    sideways or backward directional attack
>
> **Scepter of the Pious**
>
> 1. Attack: 237, Magic: +150
> 2. Uses Magic stat in damage calculation
> 3. Performs two-hit aerial warp strike
> 4. Assumes different forms based on directional input
> 5. Blitz initial hit: Trident of the Oracle
> 6. Non-directional Blitz combo: Sword of the Wise
> 7. Forward directional Blitz combo: Sword of the Tall (ends in Axe of the Conqueror)
> 8. Sideways directional Blitz combo: Blade of the Mystic (no self-buff)
> 9. Backward directional Blitz combo (Trident of the Oracle)
>
> **Sword of the Tall**
>
> 1. Use like a greatsword
> 2. Attack: 518
> 3. Has serrated blade that deals multiple hits per attack, with later
>    hits dealing higher damage
> 4. Performs warp-strike that can deal more than 10 hits
> 5. Breakage multiplier of .50 is applied to all attacks but warp-strikes
>
> **Bow of the Clever**
>
> 1. Uses Magic stat to calculate damage
> 2. Attack: 203, Magic: +80
> 3. Handles like a firearm with dagger-like mobility
> 4. Projectiles are slow and can easily miss from a distance but have a
>    maximum range of 80 feet
> 5. Attacks have lower damage modifier but can pierce enemies
> 6. Deals bonus damage to enemies in Vulnerable condition
> 7. Has special warp-strike that tops in front of enemy and shoots three
>    arrows rapidly at close range
>
> **Star of the Rogue**
>
> 1. Handles like long-range pair of daggers
> 2. Attack: 177
> 3. Has multi-hit warp-strike ending with backward evasive flip
> 4. Allows directional aerial attacks during Blitz
> 5. Standard attacks pierce enemies
> 6. Max range of 130 feet for regular, 65 feet for warp-strikes
>
> **Mace of the Fierce**
>
> 1. Use like a greatsword
> 2. Attack: 334
> 3. Has slow and linear attacks that don’t track well against fast enemies
>    but all attacks can break
> 4. Performs slow to-hit warp strike
> 5. Great for well-timed attacks
> 6. All other attacks have minor damage modifier (including parries) but
>    major breakage multipliers
>
> **Swords of the Wanderer**
>
> 1. Handles like daggers when weapon is dual-wielded during Blitz combo
>    but has weaker mid-Blitz attacks overall
> 2. Attack: 153
> 3. Has multi-hit warp strike
> 4. Has slower, focused hits in combined form as forward directional
>    attack
> 5. Allows evasive leap with subsequent aerial dive attack as sideways or
>    backward directional attack
>
> **Shield of the Just**
>
> 1. Handles like regular shield, including warp-strike
> 2. Attack: 251, Strength: -100
> 3. Hold square or x to enter defensive stance similar to taking cover.
>    Generates same HP but drains MP
>
> **Sword of the Father**
>
> 1. Handles like Sword of the Wise but has unique attack animations such
>    as a three-hit warp-strike with follow-up afterimage attacks
> 2. Attack: 141, Strength: +100
> 3. Enables unique Tenacious self-buff via a Blitz finale, increasing
>    Noctis’ Strength by 200 for 5 seconds
>
> **Axe of the Conqueror**
>
> 1. Use like a greatsword
> 2. Attack: 483, Strength: +60
> 3. Performs aerial dive warp-strike
> 4. Has slow, powerful, linear attacks
> 5. Enables aerial diving attack as forward directional attack
>
> **Katana of the Warrior**
>
> 1. Handles like sword but has extended range and faster Blitz combos
>    after initial hit
> 2. Attack: 361
> 3. Has delayed single-hit warp-strike and lets you chain successive
>    warp-strikes quickly

Comment: This seems like pretty much a definitive answer since you list all of them and even their 'hidden' effects. +1 and accepted, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The biggest reason to user royal arms are the stat boosts. A very viable and highly suggested strategy is to equip 3 royal arms and one actually "used" weapon or spell, to maximize the stat bonuses. Personally, I use the sword of the father and Axe of the conqueror in two slots as they increase str, which increases Noctis' dmg per hit. I then use the star of the roue just to have a ranged option, but Sword of the Wise is a good option for well rounded stats, and shield of the just is great for HP and defense, but it takes away stength. If your have built as a mage, there are arms such as the Scepter of the Pious that give a bonus to magic, and even uses magic for its normal attack damage.

They are also useful against enemies who are resistant to elements and/or weapon types. Royal arms all have no elemental affinity and also do not "count" as any weapon type for damage resistance. So if an enemy has two handed sword resistance, you can use the Sword of the Tall, or Axe of the Conqueror royal arm, you will bypass that resistance.

As a side not, if the enemy has an elemental resistance you want to exploit, but has weapon resistances that dont make you happy, you can use Ignus' Enhancement ability on your royal arm to give it the elemental damage bonus while still avoiding the weapon resistance of the enemy.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out a little secret behind the notoriosly mediocre royal arms after equipping four at a time. Not only does it boost my stats, but somehow, when I have 4 royal arms equipped, Noctis can't be hit by projectiles. It looks like Noctis is being shielded with tiny royal arms and I can prove it as I tried only 3 (katana, shield, star) and it didn't work. When I added the Sword of the Father, I started getting the effect. I'm still testing other combinations, though.

EDIT: so ive just tested it. Turns out, you only need the sword of father equipped for the bladeguard(that would be what ill call it now) To work.

EDIT 2: ive tested all arms already. Turns out, all royal arms has bladeguard. And only royal arms. I could be wrong but, as i test these, im using the kingly raiment. It could be the suit+arms.

Comment: PS. You need to be using the phase button, the L1 i think for it to work

Answer (score -1):

equip the best get for stat boosting solely. i havent found them overly useful for combat, but you can get some epic set ups to buff primary use weapon

Comment: This is kind of bare-bones for an answer. Could you elaborate maybe on the useful combinations you've discovered? As I unlock more of them, it's clear they have specific design goals for each one, so many some framework on how to utilize their bonuses well would make  for a great answer.