# Why am I getting damaged while attacking?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

When I am attacking someone that is just standing there, it seems that I get hit when I hit them. Is there some type of block/parry feature for enemies that you do to them? What is the best way to dodge something like this?

Comment: Are you attacking with a Royal Arm?

Comment: yes i am. is that why? i'm using the axe to do a link strike then i switch to sword of wisdom to attack faster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you are using the [Royal Arms](http://finalfantasyxv.wiki.fextralife.com/Royal+Arms). When fighting with Royal Arms, you take damage every time you strike an enemy

> Royal Arms in Final Fantasy XV (also called Armiger Weapons or Phantom Weapons) are special Weapons that Noctis can wield after finding them in the tombs of past kings. **Using these drains your HP constantly so they must be handled with care**

If they constantly drain your health, what good are they for? My answer to [What are the benefits of using royal arms?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/292912/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-royal-arms/292982#292982) gives a breakdown to why you would want to use a one in combat

Comment: You can also offset the hp loss with hp regen accesories or just spam potions :)